# Custom routing and RedirectToAction doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, redirecttoaction

Action:

```
public virtual ActionResult Index(string msg, int id)
{
    ViewBag.Message = msg;
    ViewBag.BookingOfficeGroupId = id;
    return View();
}
```

Controller Name: `UserController`

RouteConfig:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "UserPro", // Route name
                "UserPro/{action}/{msg}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "User" } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

it *works* fine when I input url directly as

```
http://localhost:83331/UserPro/Index/ssssss/0
```

but *doesn't work* with `RedirectToAction`

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "UserPro"
                            , new { 
                                msg = "Welcome"
                                , id= 0 
                            });
```

It gives me error resource not found. Where I am mistaken?

**Edit**

I just tried this url in browser and it doesn't work. Gives same error

```
http://localhost:83331/UserPro/Index?msg=Welcome&id=1
```

Comment: Your `RedirectToAction()` is to `NPSFeedbackController` - do you have other specific routes that or the Default route after you `UserPro` route?

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for pointing out that, but I am still getting same error...

Comment: OK, it needs to be `return RedirectToAction("Index", "User", new  {....`

Comment: But I want URL to be `http://localhost:83331/UserPro/Index/Welcome/0`

Comment: I know - try it :)

Comment: Tried, url is `http://localhost:83331/User/Index/Welcome/0` I have added one more scenario in my question which gives same error

Comment: Do you have other routes in you `RouteConfig.cs` file?

Comment: Yes, first I thought that would be the problem but when it is working fine by putting url in browser, it cleared my doubt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112789/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-anonymous).

Comment: Stephen is correct. You need to post your entire route configuration so we can see what route is actually matching your `RedirectToAction` request. The reason why `/UserPro/Index/Welcome/0` works and `RedirectToAction` does not are because the first case executes `RouteTable.GetRouteData()` and the second case executes `RouteTable.GetVirtualPath()`. These methods should be mirror images in most cases, but they are completely separate pieces of code which could differ greatly if you have custom routes or constraints in your route table.